# Should I use AlarmManager or JobScheduler for this?

Tags: java, android, task, alarmmanager, job-scheduling

I have a table in my database where each row describes a schedule. For example:

```
ID   |  CODE   |   DAY    |   TIME
___________________________________
1        1          Mon       8
2        27         Wed       15
```

In other words, every Monday at 8 am, the function corresponding to code 1 is called. Every Wednesday at 3 pm, the function corresponding to code 27 is called, etc.

What's the right way to call ALL these tasks at their proper times in Android? I've seen both AlarmManager and JobScheduler but I don't know which one is more appropriate to use for something like this.

I don't need the times to be super precise (having the events trigger +/- a few seconds or even minutes from the designated times is not a huge deal), but I do need them to trigger whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Alarm Manager will be more appropriate as one way or the other what you are trying to do maps upon the requirement of creating alarms.

Comment: Would I need to create PendingIntents for every single schedule, starting/stopping on every single Activity, etc?

Comment: Since you are using another app i.e. Alarm Manager to perform the task so yes you have to grant them rights i.e. PendingIntents.

Comment: I mean do you have to use one PendingIntent per row in the db, and do I have to start/stop each one in every Activity?

Comment: You can add a listener that whenever a new row in db is added AlarmManager should do its job. Yes you have to start/stop in every activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to trigger event with schedule without network or charge check, Alarm Manager is lightweight and working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library for quick Alarm Manager implementation.

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4755

Answer (score 0):

Use AlarmManager with `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle`

Be aware that on marshmallow and later, task scheduled with AlarmManager might be delayed due to [Doze](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html). The only way to get exact timing is to use `setAlarmClock` which might display an alarm clock icon in the status bar on some system.